# Origin set to geometry automatically after P separate

Tags: origin

Any suggestions? Is it me that need it as a standard "feature". I laugh at me as expect logical or negative logical blender implementation but this is something between.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be this option when you separate but once you've separated, if you select all the parts and right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry, it will do it for all the selected objects

Comment: The result is quite different as it moves geometry to origin of the origin object that separation was done from.